# How does Indestructible interact with Akarat's Champion Prophet?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-crusader

Indestructible

> When you receive fatal damage, you instead become immune to damage, gain 35% increased damage and gain 107284 Life per Kill for 5 seconds.
>
> This effect may occur once every 60 seconds.

Akarat's Champion - Prophet

> Explode with the power of your order, increasing your damage by 35% and increasing your Wrath regeneration by 5 for 20 seconds.
>
> Prophet rune: Gain 150% additional Armor while Akarat's Champion is active.
> The first time you take fatal damage while Akarat's Champion is active, you will be returned to full health.

Which triggers first?

Comment: Interesting question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [this video of Dossou](http://www.twitch.tv/dossouthedk/b/565918273), it looks like Indestructible triggers first. Any additional background/reasoning (such as always passives then actives) would be appreciated though.

Comment: I have confirmed this as of 2.1.1